# Initial skeleton for Firefox extensions?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, scaffolding

I always seem to have a hard time starting a new Firefox extension.  Can anyone recommend a good extension skeleton, scaffold, or code generator?  Ideally one that follows all the best practices for FF extensions?

Comment: can't post an answer but ill post this comment: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works nice: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder

Of course googling for "firefox extension generator" is where I found it ;)

Comment: Dead link :( but Google is still alive, hopefully! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Builder

Answer (score 2):

Look up this eclipse plugin:

[SPKet](http://spket.com)

It will take care of the skeleton and 50 other things, you will love it.