# i want to develop an add-on for mozilla

Tags: firefox

i want to develop an add-on for mozilla which will browse and give every detail of the song that you're playing on your system now !!.. is it possible?.. how to know which song i am playin ? . which ebooks to follow to develop an extension

Comment: Mozilla... Thunderbird? SeaMonkey? Camino? Bugzilla? Fennec? Ubiquity? Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129993/initial-skeleton-for-firefox-extensions) has a good extension scaffold generator.

Mozilla also provides "[Let's build a Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_addons_developer_guide/Let%27s_build_a_Firefox_extension)."

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Jetpack](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/), the new, easy way to create Firefox add-ons.